# Azure ARM dependson database clause

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I have following resource in ARM

```
{
    "name": "[parameters('dbServerName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "SqlServer"
    },
    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
    "properties": {
      "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbuser')]",
      "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbpassword')]",
      "version": "12.0"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "name": "[parameters('dbName')]",
        "type": "databases",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
          "displayName": "[parameters('dbName')]"
        },
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[parameters('dbServerName')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
          "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
          "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
          "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "[parameters('hivedbName')]",
        "type": "databases",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
          "displayName": "[parameters('hivedbName')]"
        },
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[parameters('dbServerName')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
          "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
          "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
          "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "[parameters('ooziedbName')]",
        "type": "databases",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
          "displayName": "[parameters('ooziedbName')]"
        },
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[parameters('dbServerName')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
          "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
          "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
          "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "firewallrules",
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[parameters('dbServerName')]"
        ],
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
        "properties": {
          "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
          "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

want to have another resource dependson above so I tried adding following in the dependson in my next resource

```
[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers,'/',parameters('dbServerName'),'/databases/',parameters('hivedbName'))]
```

But got following error :

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:46:59 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'Circular dependency detected on resource: '/subscriptions/######/resourceGroups/QA/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sparkqa/databases/SparkQAHive'.
```

Then I tried

```
"dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('dbServerName'))]",
      "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers,'/',parameters('dbServerName'),'/databases/',parameters('hivedbName'))]"

    ],
```

But it still start deploying the resources even before `concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers,'/',parameters('dbServerName'),'/databases/',parameters('hivedbName'))` is created

Here is the complete template https://paste.fedoraproject.org/454465/14767382/raw/

Anyone know whats wrong here ?

Comment: post your complete json template after the change

Comment: I have added the link for complete template, here in case https://paste.fedoraproject.org/454465/14767382/raw/

Comment: So the HDInsight cluster is created before the SQL Server and DB? How do you observe that?

Comment: it creates storage account & SQL server first then before creating databases it start creating HDInsight cluster. I checked in fresh deployment in resource group.

Answer (score 0):

You should depend on the actual resource, not just on the sql server name:

```
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
            ],
```

Comment: I have updated my question, didn't work with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working well with the following format:

`"dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('serverName'), variables('dbName'))]"],`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).